# Ожидание условия в C++ (фичи с лямбдами)

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, условия, unreal-engine-4

Хочу реализовать в C++ способ ожидания условия с помощью таймера.
То есть после ожидания должно выполниться какое-либо действие.

Выглядеть это дело должно примерно в итоге так:

```
WAIT_FOR_CONDITION(
    [&] { 
        return IsDone;
    },
    [&] {
        PRINT("Done!");
    }
);
```

Как можно заметить тут используются лямбды, которые захватывают все ссылки, в том числе и this.

Конструкция довольно интересная и вероятно она может иногда ускорить работу, сократить время разработки.

Однако возникают очень много странностей при попытках реализовать это.
Я использую таймеры в движке Unreal Engine 4. Таймеры там - это сущности, которые просто вызывают делегаты.

```
template<typename FunctorConditionType, typename FunctorActionType>
inline FTimerHandle WaitForCondition(UWorld* World, float delay, const FunctorConditionType& condition, const FunctorActionType& action)
{
    FTimerDelegate TimerCallback;
    FTimerHandle Handle;


    TimerCallback.BindLambda([&World, &condition, &action, &Handle, &TimerCallback] {
        PRINT("Waiting for condition");
        if (condition())
        {
            action();
            checkf(World, TEXT("World is not exist"));
            TimerCallback.Unbind();
            World->GetTimerManager().ClearTimer(Handle);
            PRINT("Waiting for condition... done!");
        } else
        {
            PRINT("Waiting for condition... failed try");
        }
    });

    World->GetTimerManager().SetTimer(Handle, TimerCallback, delay, true, delay);
    return Handle;
}

#define WAIT_FOR_CONDITION(delay, condition, action) WaitForCondition(GetWorld(), delay, condition, action)
```

Выглядит это так. Использую в итоге макрос WAIT_FOR_CONDITION, потому-что метод GetWorld() доступен почти везде.
Собственно о самих странностях: внутри этих лямбд почему-то пропадают все ссылки. Всё становится nullptr, даже this (а это самое важное).
В функции WaitForCondition создаётся ещё одна лямбда, внутри которой вызываются лямбды указанные в параметрах.
Кто-нибудь пытался сделать подобное? Если да, то поделитесь опытом и укажите на мои ошибки.
Возникает мысль, что следует использовать [=] вместо [&], однако это означает, что все данные просто будут скопированы? Но там могут быть большие объёмы данных.

Поправьте меня, если я говорю что-то не так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну как минимум `TimerCallback` и `Handle` являются локальными переменными для `WaitForCondition` поэтому при выходе из нее обе переменный будут удалены а ссылки которые переданы в лямбду станут не корректными. При обращении к таким ссылкам вы получаете UB. По остальным переменным не могу судить точно, но судя по вашим описаниям происходит тоже самое.

Иными словами, ссылки переданные в лямбду - самые обычные ссылки, объекты на которые они ссылаются должны "жить" на момент обращения к ним.

Решение: либо копируйте объекты, либо продлите им "жизнь" до завершения лямбды.

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь всё понятно.